# regular expression example

Tags: php, regex

I have problem understanding this one:

```
<?php
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Output is `April1,2003`. I don't understand this expression: `$replacement = '${1}1,$3';`
Would appreciate if somebody clarifies it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmer had to use this, because

```
$replacement = '$11,$3';
```

would act weird and wrong. Also, they couldn't use

```
$replacement = '$1'.'1,$3';
```

too,because it would cause it to be parsed as the first example.

That's why there are these brackets, they work as a delimiter between the variable and number `1`.

It's the same as

```
$username = "Martin"
$text = "Hello ${username}and welcome";
```

above example will output "Hello Martinand welcome"

but this one

```
$username = "Martin";
$text = "Hello $usernameand welcome";
```

is mistchmashing the variable name with plain text, which is in your replacement, number `1`

Comment: No it's not. Yours pattern misses April in it's output.

Answer (score 1):

The `${1}` syntax is referencing the first capture group from the pattern match. This is necessary in this particular case because the desired output from the replacement is the first capture group followed by a literal `1`.

This is a result of how backreferences are processed in regex context by php. The `${1}` is necessary to separate the backreference from the literal `1`. Had the pattern been `$11` instead, php would think `$11` was a reference to the eleventh capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is that you're constructing `$replacement` variable beforehand and all string concatenation happens before preg_replace is called. Take this example:

Let's say you had:

```
$replacement = '$1' . '1';
```

What this will do is to put value `$11` into your variable $replacement and when preg_replace is called it will try to find a back-reference # 11 by using replacement as `$11` and obviously it doesn't exist.

Now if you change it to:

```
$replacement = '$1' . ' ';
```

It will have value `$1` and your replacement will correctly **correctly** to `'April '`.

**About use of curly braces:** Curly braces are used to explicitly specify the end of a variable name hence this works fine:

```
$replacement = '${1}' . '1';
```

And replaces the string to `'April1`